# Cable for SFF-8087 to SAS drives

Tags: sas, dell-perc

I have a bunch of 3.5" SAS hard drives that I removed from one of my raid enclosures that has a backplane and want to reuse those drives with a Perc H700 controller in a PC that is a full tower system so it doesn't have a backplane in it.  But want to reuse the drives there.  Any recommendations for a cable that would go from SFF-8087 to 4 SAS connectors with power?  I thought the breakout cables I had were what I needed but they were just 8087 to SATA connectors.

Thanks.

JR

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use "Mini SFF 8087 to 4x SFF 8482" cables. With two of those breakout cables, you can connect up to 8 drives to that card.

Keep in mind that there will be a separate power connection for each drive.

I've bought that cable in both SATA and Molex power connector variants, and the SATA ones are much easier to deal with in my opinion... Especially the ones with a SATA power connector directly on the SFF 8482 plug, with no power cable dangling off the end of each connector end. Much less cluttered cabling that way.